# While login on web via Facebook Native App on mobile then session is lost

Tags: android, facebook, web, oauth-2.0

I have Facebook login on my website. When user tries to log in, then they are asked whether they want use native app for this. If they select to use it, then after successfully login Facebook App redirects user on my redirect url within a Webview in Facebook App.

But I want that users are still in browser, not in a Webview.

Because there is another session, if they select "Open in chrome" from Webview menu, then they are not logged in anymore.

Someone knows how to solve this problem? Is there a way to tell (via URL) to Android to not to use native app for login. Or, maybe, to tell native app to redirect back into browser, not Webview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an open bug report on Facebook's [developer support forum](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/367199853974993/)